# How to access file explorer with HTML Automatically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to make a link that accesses File Explorer so a user can insert images. I have heard that you can do this in Internet Explorer, but since Chrome is more popular, I was wondering if there was a way that I can access File explorer with a link in Chrome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the `file` input type.
This opens up the file explorer for you so you can upload files.

```html
<input type="file" />
```

It also has a optional attribute called `accept` which lets your input only accept certain file types. For example the code below will only allow images to be uploaded:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Here is the link to the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

By the way, such input types **can't** be styled directly.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot!